# Unable to change band rendering style of rasters in QGIS 2.10.1

Tags: qgis, style

I am new to QGIS.

I have multiple DEM raster files (.tif) added to my map. However, I am unable to alter any of the style options under the "Band Rendering" section.

I have attempted to make changes and then save it as a new style, just clicking okay, just clicking apply, etc. Yet, every time, the original style choices are still there when I reopen the raster's properties. I am able to make changes to all other style options.

I'm particularly interesting in changing the color gradient from "Black to white" to "White to black".

Comment: If you are working on a Mac, this might be a known bug: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156324/unable-to-stylize-as-pseudocolor-render-type-on-mac-osx. If not, please provide some screenshots.

Comment: You are correct, I am working on a Mac. Thank you very much for the link, my searching for previous threads failed to pick this up.

Comment: According to http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13162 the matter should be fixed in the latest builds by http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/.