# Cannot change an SRTM raster rendering with single band pseudocolour

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-2, rendering, srtm

I'm trying to colorize a SRTM raster in QGIS 2.10 following a tutorial found on the [Ireland QGIS User Group Blog](https://ieqgis.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/create-great-looking-topographic-maps-in-qgis-2/). My problem is that when I try to set the render type as `single band pseudocolour` in the Style Preferences, nothing happens and the raster rendering remains unchanged. Then when I open again the Style Preferences, everything is default-set.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you working QGIS on a Mac? The reason  I am asking is this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166180/unable-to-change-band-rendering-style-of-rasters-in-qgis-2-10-1

Comment: Yes I'm on OS X, thanks for the link. So my question should be marked as duplicate I guess ? Gonna try to find out how to do this.