# Low quality when applying hillshade on specific DEM

Tags: qgis, hillshade, bathymetry, cyprus

I've been using GIS for a dissertation project and am having a little trouble with using a hillshade on a specific DEM.

My project is looking at Cyprus, and as such I've looked around and found a really helpful Mosaic to Raster DEM file that looks to be of high quality.

When I run a hillshade on it however, it looks awful and doesn't really c. I know it's not an issue with this DEM, and definitely an issue with me as I have the same problem with Bathymetry data too.

I've attached a couple of images of what I mean to hopefully better explain, but the gist of it is the hillshade looks awful when coloured, and nothing like it should. Similarly, this is the case for Bathymetry data, even when I alter the normal 345 angle to account for reversal.

Wondering if anyone could help, would be massive boon to this project getting a few really high quality maps in there.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Above is an album to my issue. Maybe it's a colour problem? But no matter what I try, it looks ugly.

Big props to the creator of the mosaic to raster - Paraskeva Charalambos, University of Edinburgh

Comment: *'it looks awful'*... How is it suppose to look?

Comment: It is a color problem...A hillshade should represent the variations in shadows on a grayscale. Notice that the values range from 0 (total dark) to 255 (total light). If you want that the color represent heights, you must use the original DEM, apply a color scheme, define that the DEM a transparency about 50%.The order of the layers also matters, Put firs the dem and below the hillshade

Comment: look at his: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165792/qgis-elevation-and-relief-shade/165817#165817

Comment: Thanks for the replies! With a custom colour map the guy made it look like this. https://imgur.com/a/34zLl I'll give your suggestion a go Gerardo and see what it looks like. So don't apply the colours to the hillshade? Just the original DEM?

Comment: Gerardo Jimenez thank you so much! Looks so so so much better. Genuinely chuffed! :)

Comment: Do you have any idea how I'd accurately go about producing a hillshade for bathymetry data?

Comment: as an addition to Gerardos suggestion: instead of the transparent overlay I tend to use a color mix mode. place the colored dem on top of the hillshade and select style -> color rendering -> blending mode and choose *burn* or *multiply*. you can fiddle with the rendering settings like brightness etc. if you want. as for the bathymetry data: if it is a DEM, do the same? choose an appropriate color scheme maybe. or what format is that data?

Comment: Hi! Yeah I've tried the same process, and it doesn't exactly seem to represent depth. I've attached a link showing the original bathymetry DEM and then the hillshade, and then the DEM overlaying the hillshade using the processes described here. https://imgur.com/a/qsQ9n Maybe that's how it's meant to look, but it doesn't appear to represent depth as well as the original DEM. Also the data seems to be a pretty awful resolution, can't find any better elsewhere unfortunately.

Comment: check this http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/views/topobath.html Those are some topo-bathymetry color ramps. You can dowload the svg version and use the svg2color plugin to use them with qgis. Once you import them in to qgis with svg2color they will be availabe for any project